# MS ACCESS error after compiling code

Tags: ms-access

After compiling my access database I get an error when starting the database. 
When I run the non compiled version of the database it works fine.

The error says `the expression you entered has a function name that <database name> can't find`.

I have read that this error is caused by a macro trying to run a vba function that does not exist.

The only macro I have is the `autoexec` macro and that calls a startup vba function.

Like I said the non compiled access database is fine only the compiled version generates this error.

Why would this error occur after compiling?

Comment: Go to menu Tools, References, and you most likely will see a reference marked MISSING. Resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I compiled the VBA code in the VBA editor.